# WPF ComboBox Formatting

Tags: wpf, combobox

This works perfectly, except that I need some kind of template to display the Selected Item of the ComboBox? Currently the bindings work as expected, but the ComboBox displays: "Systems.Windows.Controls.ListView Items.Count:20".

I would like it to display a horizontal StackPanel or Grid containing the GridViewColumn items (ID, Closed Date, Customer, Job Name).

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                      IsTextSearchEnabled="False" Width="700"                                   
                      IsEditable="True">

                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveJobObservCollection}" 
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedActiveJob, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Job ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding JobID}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Closed Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ClosedDate, StringFormat=d}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Customer Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CustomerName}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="300" Header="Job Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding JobName}"/>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your issue correctly, that you want to display this 4 columns (ID, Closed Date, Customer, Job Name) in horizontal manner where data is coming from this `ActiveJobObservCollection` collection

if that is the case then bind `itemsource` and `selecteditem` property directly to `gridview` instead of `listview`.